# Load object with DBFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, dbflow

I'm trying to load a full object using db-flow on Android but It doesn't work properly.

The documentation [says](https://agrosner.gitbooks.io/dbflow/content/Relationships.html):

> For efficiency reasons we recommend specifying
>   `@ForeignKey(stubbedRelationship = true)`. What this will do is only
>   preset the primary key references into a table object. All other
>   fields will not be set. If you need to access the full object, you
>   will have to call load() for Model, or use the ModelAdapter to load
>   the object from the DB.

And:

> Also if you don't specify `@Database(foreignKeyConstraintsEnforced=true)`
>   , calling load() may not have any effect. Essentially without
>   enforcing `@ForeignKey` at an SQLite level, you can end up with floating
>   key references that do not exist in the referenced table.

AppDatabase:

```
@Database(version = AppDatabase.VERSION, 
        generatedClassSeparator = "_", 
        foreignKeyConstraintsEnforced = true)

object AppDatabase {

    const val NAME = "AppDatabase"
    const val VERSION = 1
}
```

The data entity:

```
@Parcelize
@Table(database = AppDatabase::class)
data class Checklist(
        @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
        var id: Long = 0,


        @ForeignKeyReference(foreignKeyColumnName = "idReference", columnName = "category_id")
        @ForeignKey(onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE,
                onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE,
                stubbedRelationship = true)
        var module: Module? = null,

}
```

The dao function:

```
suspend fun save(checklist: Checklist) {
    withContext(ioContext) {
        modelAdapter<Checklist>().save(checklist)
    }
}
```

The retrieve function:

```
suspend fun getChecklist(id: Long): Checklist? = withContext(ioContext) {
        SQLite.select()
                .from(Checklist::class.java)
                .where(Checklist_Table.id.`is`(id))
                .querySingle()
    }
```

Here is the problem. When I load the Checklist object, the module attribute isn't loaded which is referenced on Checklist.

```
fun loadChecklist(checklist: Checklist){
    modelAdapter<Checklist>().load(checklist)
    if(checklist.module != null)
        System.out.print("module loded")
    else
        System.out.print("module isn't loaded")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem using the function:

```
modelAdapter<Module>().load(checklist.module, FlowManager.getWritableDatabase(AppDatabase::class.java))
```

Now I have the module loaded.